# can we develop web application using WSL?

Tags: laravel, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I just knew about the WSL and I just want to ask if it will work like we have another operating system. so if I will enable this in my machine I can develop web applications using some Linux image like ubuntu?. and install all the stuff I needed for my project like Nginx MySQL on the WSL?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can basically get the Linux terminal in windows with the capability of installing packages and executing programs and you can even configure windows tools like Jetbrain clion or Pycharm to compile programs in wsl environment.